# How I get model attribute in Vue?

Tags: spring, model

How can i get Model Attribute in Vue?
This is My controller in backend(Spring).

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
@PutMapping("/board/postlist")
public String boardList(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("posts", postService.findAllDesc());
    model.addAttribute("attrTest", "WHATTHOE");
    return "IndexController.update() working";
}
```

`posts`is a List.First, I guess my list or sth was wrong. So i add another String attribute `attrTest` but still in problem...
And this is my vue template.

```
      <b-textarea placeholder="${attrTest}"></b-textarea>
```

And this is part of my vue script.

```
<script>
export default {
      name: "postList",
      data: ()=>({
        content:'',
        author:'',
      })
    }
    </script>
```

Screen just display ${attrTest}, in text. It doesn't seem recognize variable.

I been searching many solutions but it doesn't work for me. I tried ${} like jquery but also failed. Maybe my project doesn't have jquery... i can't found jquery in my pakage.json too.

In mustache, i just write {{#posts}} for get model atrribution. Also use Axios result succesfuly but is it impossible to get model attribute with Vue solution? like $attr or sth.
Is it necessary to install jquery?

now I don't no where to start. I tried get `posts` list all day long. I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Thymeleaf as view resolver, try th:placeholder